# Properly encode URL for Webtest configuration XML with Terraform on Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure, azure-monitoring

I'm trying to setup a `azurerm_application_insights_web_test` with Terraform. Currently having issues with the `Url` parameter in the `configuration` WebTest XML.

I'm just not figuring out how I'd have to properly encode the string. For "simple" URLs, it's no problem. But what about eg. https://a.skwar.me/example=yes? The problem is with the "=" (equal) sign in the URL.

If I set `Url="https://a.skwar.me/example=yes"` in the XML, `terraform apply` fails:

```
2021-12-03T08:32:47.4173868Z Error: creating/updating Application Insights Web Test: (Name "dummy3aaiwt" / Resource Group "SharedienDevopsTesting"): insights.WebTestsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: Web test 'dummy3aaiwt' is invalid. Ensure it is a well formed XML and that it adheres to the web test schema. Technical error: '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 23, position 33." InnerError={"diagnosticcontext":"6a6fb5be-fba9-4110-be6a-beffd2a44ef1","time":"2021-12-03T08:32:47.3359710Z"}
```

Note: **Technical error: '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'**

I tried to simply `urlencode()` the whole URL. Apply works, but no tests are being done. If I go Azure Portal, I see that the parameter hasn't been decoded; ie. I see `https%3A%2F%2Fa.skwar.me%2Fexample%3Dyes`. I also cannot save the test, as the URL is invalid (… d'oh!)

I've got this:

```
resource "azurerm_application_insights_web_test" "dummy3" {

  name = "dummy3aaiwt"

  location                = local.ai_this.location
  resource_group_name     = local.ai_this.resource_group_name
  application_insights_id = local.ai_this.id
  kind                    = "ping"
  frequency               = 900
  timeout                 = 120
  enabled                 = true
  retry_enabled           = true
  geo_locations           = split(",", local.test_locations)

  configuration = <<XML
<WebTest
  Name="abcdefXML"
  Id="${random_uuid.dummy.result}"
  Enabled="True"
  CssProjectStructure=""
  CssIteration=""
  Timeout="120"
  WorkItemIds=""
  xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010"
  Description=""
  CredentialUserName=""
  CredentialPassword=""
  PreAuthenticate="True"
  Proxy="default"
  StopOnError="False"
  RecordedResultFile=""
  ResultsLocale="">
    <Items>
        <Request
          Method="GET"
          Guid="${random_uuid.dummy2.result}"
          Version="1.1"
          Url="${urlencode("https://a.skwar.me/some-exampe?foo=bar")}"
          ThinkTime="0"
          Timeout="120"
          ParseDependentRequests="False"
          FollowRedirects="True"
          RecordResult="True"
          Cache="False"
          ResponseTimeGoal="0"
          Encoding="utf-8"
          ExpectedHttpStatusCode="302"
          ExpectedResponseUrl=""
          ReportingName=""
          IgnoreHttpStatusCode="False" />
    </Items>
</WebTest>
XML
}
```

Comment: hello @alexander Skwar, if i don't use urlencode and provide this `https://a.skwar.me/some-exampe?foo=bar` directly , it works fine

Comment: I am using Terraform v1.0.11
on windows_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.86.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ***Terraform Version 1.0.11 and provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.86.0*** , if I try to use `urlencode` in the url parameter then I am also facing the same issue that you see in portal as below:

[image]

But directly providing the URL using the below code succeeds and URL is also correctly defined in portal and can be saved as well.

```
resource "azurerm_application_insights_web_test" "example" {
  name                    = "tf-test-appinsights-webtest"
  location                = data.azurerm_application_insights.example.location
  resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_application_insights.example.resource_group_name
  application_insights_id = data.azurerm_application_insights.example.id
  kind                    = "ping"
  frequency               = 300
  timeout                 = 60
  enabled                 = true
  geo_locations           = ["us-ca-sjc-azr", "us-va-ash-azr"]

configuration = <<XML
<WebTest
  Name="WebTest1"
  Id="ABD48585-0831-40CB-9069-682EA6BB3583"
  Enabled="True"
  CssProjectStructure=""
  CssIteration=""
  Timeout="120"
  WorkItemIds=""
  xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010"
  Description=""
  CredentialUserName=""
  CredentialPassword=""
  PreAuthenticate="True"
  Proxy="default"
  StopOnError="False"
  RecordedResultFile=""
  ResultsLocale="">
    <Items>
        <Request
          Method="GET"
          Guid="a5f10126-e4cd-570d-961c-cea43999a200"
          Version="1.1"
          Url="https://a.skwar.me/some-exampe?foo=bar"
          ThinkTime="0"
          Timeout="300"
          ParseDependentRequests="False"
          FollowRedirects="True"
          RecordResult="True"
          Cache="False"
          ResponseTimeGoal="0"
          Encoding="utf-8"
          ExpectedHttpStatusCode="302"
          ExpectedResponseUrl=""
          ReportingName=""
          IgnoreHttpStatusCode="False" />
    </Items>
</WebTest>
XML
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, indeed, works fine - also for me. No idea what it was. But it somehow seems to be related to the length of the URL. It fails with the following URL, which is an amzon.de search for Schönes (nice): https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Sch%C3%B6nes